# PHP How to get continue date next month based on number of parameters?

Tags: php

How to get continue date next month based on number of parameters?

Example:

```
$loan = 4; //count from this month
$fixedDateEveryMonth = 28;

for($i=0 $i<=$loan; $i++)
{
    echo $fixedDateEveryMonth."-".date("m-y");
}
```

So what I expected is to get below date:

```
28-Apr-2019
28-May-2019
28-Jun-2019
28-Jul-2019
```

Any idea?

Comment: What if the fixed Date is the 31st?

Comment: The fixed date will be only 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do what you want. It creates a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object from the start date, and then adds 1 month to the date through the loop:

```
$loan = 4;
$fixedDateEveryMonth = 28;
$start = new DateTime(date('Y-m-') . $fixedDateEveryMonth);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $loan; $i++) {
    $start->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
    echo $start->format('d-M-Y') ."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
28-Apr-2019
28-May-2019
28-Jun-2019
28-Jul-2019
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/eEo1I)

Comment: Hi Nick, I continue my question on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295170/php-get-continue-date-next-month-and-get-price-loan-every-month-with-interest-pa